# What's wrong with this Java Linked List representation of a stack of integers?

Tags: java, linked-list, stack

Okay, so with the following code I get a nullpointer exception from everything in my pop method. Therefore, I know that 'head' must be null when that method runs. Thing is I have no idea why and I've looked over my code a good bit now. Please help!

```
Here it is:
```

NODE CLASS:

```
public class StackNode{

  private StackNode link; //link to next node
  private int value;

  public StackNode(int value, StackNode linkValue){
    this.link = link;
    this.value = value;
  }
  public StackNode(){
   this.link = null;
  }
  public void setNodeData(int value){
   this.value = value; 
  }
  public void setLink(StackNode newLink){
   this.link = newLink; 
  }
  public int getValue(){
   return this.value; 
  }
  public StackNode getLink(){
   return link; 
  }
}
```

LINKED LIST CLASS:

```
public class IntStackList{

 private StackNode head;

 public IntStackList(){ this.head = null; }
 public void push(int value){
   this.head = new StackNode(value, head);
 }
 public int pop(){
   int value = this.head.getValue(); //get the int value stored in the head node
   this.head = head.getLink(); //sets the head to the next node in line
   return value;
 }
}
```

I am implementing this in a program that converts a decimal number to binary(for a class). I can print data from the first node AKA the head of the linked list but then I have the null issue when popping again.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Note: this kind of problems can be spotted by doing proper debug of the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're assigning `link` to itself in the constructor if the `StackNode`...

```
public class StackNode {

    private StackNode link; //link to next node
    private int value;

    public StackNode(int value, StackNode linkValue) {
        this.link = link;
        this.value = value;
    }
```

It should be

```
this.link = linkValue;
```